# Getting all lines as well as the initial pattern in VBA regex

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to match a pattern, and then get the next 1-3 lines after that pattern if they exist. I know I'm doing something wrong, but I'm not sure what exactly it is:

So if the string contains:

```
OUR SKED
or 
OURS SCHEDULE:
01JAN14-24FEB16
26FEB17-17FEB18
19MAR16 - 24DEC28
```

(ignore the grammar error, I need to incorporate the fact that people can't spell but may get the "gist" of it right).
I need to get that, plus the next 3 lines. Right now I'm only getting the first part matching schedule.

`((OUR[S]{0,1} S[KCH]{1,2}ED(ULE){0,1})[:]{1})((([\r\n])([0-9]{2}[\s]{0,1}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}[\s]{0,1}-[\s]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[\s]{0,1}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2})|)|){0,3}`

Using [RegExr](http://regexr.com/) the above works, however in my `Debug.Print` I'm only getting the "OUR SCHEDULE:" part.

Let me break down the above regex for clarity. The schedule part:

```
((OUR[S]{0,1} S[KCH]{1,2}ED(ULE){0,1})[:]{1})
```

The each subsequent date line, accounting for spaces and random errors:

```
((([\r\n])([0-9]{2}[\s]{0,1}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2}[\s]{0,1}-[\s]{0,1}[0-9]{2}[\s]{0,1}[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{2})|)|){0,3}
```

That will match `01JAN17-02FEB17` or `10 JAN 17 - 02 FEB 17` and everything in between.

This gets the correct first line, so I know I'm good there just don't know what else I'm missing.

I'm now using the VBA code from the first answer to test, and still only getting the first part. The VBA code to pull the match is as follows:

```
Public Function StripPatternMatchingRegex2(ByVal valueToTest As String, ByVal expression As String) As Variant
Dim regex As New RegExp
Dim results As Variant
Dim allmatches As Object
If valueToTest <> "" Then
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .Multiline = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = expression
    End With
    ' Debug.Print expression
    If regex.test(valueToTest) Then
        Set StripPatternMatchingRegex2 = regex.Execute(valueToTest)
    Else
        Set StripPatternMatchingRegex2 = Nothing
    End If
End If
End Function
```

Comment: your goal is to get the dates? why don't you target the date values?

Comment: I need them to be the dates that exist specifically after that pattern which is why I'm including that pattern. Other dates exist in that document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like

`(OUR SKED|OURS SCHEDULE:)((([\r\n]{1,2})(DDMMMYYYY - DDMMMYYYY)|)|){0,3}`

Work?
Basically, this Regex can be split up into 
"OUR SKED" OR "OURS SCHEDULE:"
then
Up to three rows of "DDMMMYYYY - DDMMMYYYYY"

You need to change the DDMMMYYY items to be however your dates are displayed (I don't know if MMM is "MAY" or supposed to be "MM"-> 05)

I put your string (with the line returns \n) in cell(1,1) and used the following code.

```
Sub Test()

Dim results As Variant
Dim i As Integer
Set results = StripPatternMatchingRegex(Cells(1, 1), "(OUR SKED|OURS SCHEDULE:)((([\r\n])(DDMMMYYYY - DDMMMYYYY)|)|){0,3}")
For i = 0 To results.Count - 1
    Debug.Print results.Item(i).Value
Next i

End Sub

Public Function StripPatternMatchingRegex(ByVal valueToTest As String, ByVal expression As String) As Variant
Dim regex As New RegExp
Dim results As Variant
Dim allmatches As Object
If valueToTest <> "" Then
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = expression
    End With
    ' Debug.Print expression
    If regex.Test(valueToTest) Then
        Set StripPatternMatchingRegex = regex.Execute(valueToTest)
    Else
        Set StripPatternMatchingRegex = Nothing
    End If
End If
End Function
```

You can test and play around with regex on a site like [RegExr](http://regexr.com/)

Comment: Took what you had, cleaned up my regex. VBA still isn't giving me anything after the schedule line, though RegExr works.

Comment: Marked it as correct, because I only needed to change `([\r\n])` to `([\r\n]{1,2})` to get it to work. THANK YOU!